# HTML/CSS Firefox problem

Tags: html, css, firefox

have a look at the top menu on these two pages on Firefox:

http://outsidemma.com/2010/100031-bj-penn-the-prodigy-jay-dee.php

http://outsidemma.com/index.php

On the first page for some reason there is some extra spacing above it.

This only happens on Firefox. I am using Firefox 3.6.

Comment: If you can't get an answer here, try DocType

Comment: I don't know why it happens, but adding "float: left" to fieldset solves the problem.

Comment: Removing "float: left" from .section would add 10 px to top menu as well. That seems to be the difference between the two sites. Hence if you want 10px top menu in both sites, remove "float: left" from .section, and if you don't want  the padding add "float: left" to fieldset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
.clearfix:after {
  clear:both;
  content:" ";
  display:block;
  font-size:0;
  height:0;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Firefox doesn't always like this rule, instead I'd do this:

```
.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Or alternatively, just give it a height so it doesn't infer line-height:

```
.clearfix:after {
  clear:both;
  content:" ";
  display:block;
  font-size:0;
  height:1px;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I added the overflow:auto attribute to my clearfix class and the problem was solved. Thanks